# Error 503 Backend fetch failed, when I pointed the domain to the IP

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, magento, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I'm using amazon lightsail, I'm using bitnami to deploy magento 2.3.1 and the latest version of wordpress. The installation went smoothly, both could be accessed from the IP address.

I added the domain to lightsail like [this](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-how-to-create-dns-entry), by following official amazon docs and varnish started giving error "Error 503 Backend fetch failed"

[This](http://sacredbasket.com) is where magento is installed. [This](http://sacredbasket.com/blog) is where the blog is installed

both powered by bitnami, both went down when I added the domain name.

I tried restarting vanish and all bitnami services, I tried restarting lightsail instance. Many say to disable vanish, I don't want to do that unless there's no other solution. Recreating the instance is possible but I doubt that it would solve anything.

Comment: Did you assign static IP before creating DNS entry?

Comment: @DavidAlsbright A static IP to the instance? Right? The thing you do immediately after creating an instance? Yes I did, last week, today tried adding the domain and it went down

Comment: Can you still access via IP?

Comment: @DavidAlsbright No I cannot. I see the same error just like when accessing via domain name

Comment: Ok, understood. I would try to check the database tables for site URL, in WordPress it should be `siteurl` row in `option_name` column, I would check that it is the new domain name and not old IP. If both M2 and WP are down maybe it is .htaccess issue, I think bitnami don't allow direct access but you have to edit config on server. bitnami support is quite good and may be able to help faster. Do the URLs work when you disable Varnish? I know you don't want to do it to fix, but might help to diagnose problem.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright Digging into the database was the first thing I thought about doing but what does it have to do with Vanish? Shouldn't it give a different error? or is it the same error only in vanish?

Comment: Let me check the possible solutions you provided and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright I deleted the instance and then recreated it from a snapshot, is it possible to use A records to point the ip to the domain? done that, not working, I don't want to create a dns zone in lightsail because I fear it would mess things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the Wordpress domain name in `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php`

Changing

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

To

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://DOMAIN/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://DOMAIN/');
```

For Magento, you need to update the hostname:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig --machine_hostname NEW_DOMAIN
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, fixed it by creating new instance